# How make url with query string to folder structure using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I have the following url structure in my website

http://domain.com/folder1/propertydetail.php?property=lorem-ipsum-title&id=1
folder1 is my project folder.That is not hosted in root.
I need to change the url to

http://domain.com/folder1/lorem-ipsum-title/1

Please help me to solve this.I have spoil my one day .

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder1/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ folder1/propertydetail.php?property=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

put this code in your .htaccess file
and change links in referring pages

for example if you pointing to http://domain.com/folder1/propertydetail.php?property=lorem-ipsum-title&id=1
then change in your html or php file to point http://domain.com/folder1/lorem-ipsum-title/1

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ $1/propertydetail.php?property=$2&id=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Above is code in my .htaccss file.But it is not working

Comment: id should be equal to $3 i.e.  &id=$3

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ $1/propertydetail.php?property=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]

Comment: how are you using the links?

Comment: you have to use the rewrite links instead of original links

Comment: http://domain.com/folder1/propertydetail.php?property=lorem-ipsum-title1&id=2

Above is the actual url in the "a" tag.When i am clicking on the " a "  tag, the url in the address bar should be in the below format
http://domain.com/folder1/lorem-ipsum-title1/2.That is what i am searching

Comment: nope! you have to use formatted link in the "a" tag like this -->domain.com/folder1/lorem-ipsum-title1/2. Because server will internally look for original link in .htacess.

Comment: you are not following i guess. please use formatted links in "a" tag. don't use actual links. i.e. `<a href=" domain.com/folder1/lorem-ipsum-title1/2">`.  if your using php then echo the values at the right places. i.e. `<a href=" domain.com/folder1/<?php echo $property ?>/<?php echo $id ?>">`. that's it. your done. :)

Comment: Given formatted url directly in a tag.domain.com/folder1/lorem-ipsum-title1/1 .But 404 error occured

Comment: Now i have changed the files to root  and worrking fine.RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/?$ /propertydetail.php?property=$1&id=$2

Comment: and what about the "a" tag.

Comment: <a href=" domain.com/<?php echo $property ?>/<?php echo $id ?>">